# Calculation Section for Numerous Items

Tags: vb.net

Here's whats going on:

Number of Shirts: (Enter number of shirts purchased here)

Number of Premium Shirts: ""

Number of Hats: ""

Number of Stickers: ""

The user enters the number that was purchased in the text boxes.

Then they click the calculate button after picking their shipping option.

The calculate button needs to calculate the sub total, then there's a sales tax label, shipping cost label, order total label.

Where I am stuck is having the sub total be calculated. In the calculation section of my calculate button, I tried coding it, but my brain just stopped working or something because I am stuck and I haven't been able to figure it out. And it's SO simple!

Here's the code I have so far. Some help would be greatly appreciated. There's some parts of the code missing, I know, because I'm stuck.

```
        'Local Variable Declaration Section
    Const csngSalesTaxRate As Single = 0.0625
    Dim sngShirtPrice As Single = 10
    Dim sngPremiumShirtPrice As Single = 20
    Dim sngHatPrice As Single = 15
    Dim sngStickerPrice As Single = 2.99
    Dim sngSubTotal As Single
    Dim sngSalesTax As Single
    Dim sngOrderTotal As Single
    Dim sngShippingCost As Single
    Dim intShirts As Integer
    Dim intHats As Integer
    Dim intStickers As Integer
    Dim intPremiumShirts As Integer
    'Data Input Section

    Try     'Checks to see if the price is a valid number.
        'If it is, then it is assigned to the quantity variable, if not, error message and the event is halted.
        sngShirtPrice = CInt(txtShirts.Text)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid number of Shirts.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK)    'Displays an error messsage when there is an invalid number
        txtShirts.Text = ""  'Clears the text box
        txtShirts.Focus()    'Puts the cursor in the price textbox
        Exit Sub    'Terminates the click event to allow valid input.
    End Try


    Try     'Checks if the quantity is a valid number.
        'If it is, then it is assigned to the quantity variable, if not, error message and event is halted.
        sngPremiumShirtPrice = CInt(txtPremiumShirts.Text)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid number of Premium Shirts.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK)    'Displays an error messsage when there is an invalid number
        txtPremiumShirts.Text = ""  'Clears the text box
        txtPremiumShirts.Focus()    'Puts the cursor in the price textbox
        Exit Sub    'Terminates the click event to allow valid input.
    End Try

    Try     'Checks if the quantity is a valid number.
        'If it is, then it is assigned to the quantity variable, if not, error message and event is halted.
        sngHatPrice = CInt(txtHats.Text)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid number of Hats.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK)    'Displays an error messsage when there is an invalid number
        txtHats.Text = ""  'Clears the text box
        txtHats.Focus()    'Puts the cursor in the price textbox
        Exit Sub    'Terminates the click event to allow valid input.
    End Try

    Try     'Checks if the quantity is a valid number.
        'If it is, then it is assigned to the quantity variable, if not, error message and event is halted.
        sngStickerPrice = CInt(txtStickers.Text)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid number of Stickers.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK)    'Displays an error messsage when there is an invalid number
        txtStickers.Text = ""  'Clears the text box
        txtStickers.Focus()    'Puts the cursor in the price textbox
        Exit Sub    'Terminates the click event to allow valid input.
    End Try

    'Calculation Section
    sngSubTotal =    'Calculates the subtotal
    sngSalesTax = sngSubTotal * csngSalesTaxRate    'Calculates Sales Tax by multiplying Subtotal by Sales Tax Rate
    sngOrderTotal = sngSubTotal + sngSalesTax 'Calculates total for the sale
    mintOrdersPlacedToday = mintOrdersPlacedToday + 1   'Calculates the number of orders placed today, adds one to the previous number

    'Output section
    lblShowSubTotal.Text = FormatCurrency(sngSubTotal)  'Displays the Sub Total
    lblShowSalesTax.Text = FormatCurrency(sngSalesTax)  'Displays the Sales Tax
    lblShowOrderTotal.Text = FormatCurrency(sngOrderTotal)  'Displays the Order Total
    lblShowOrdersPlacedToday.Text = mintOrdersPlacedToday
    lblShowOrderTotal.Text = sngOrderTotal
End Sub

Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
    Dim result = MessageBox.Show(" Are you sure you want to exit?", "Are you sure?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) 'Shows a messagebox for the user asking if they want to exit the program and gives them options.
    If result = DialogResult.Yes Then   'States that if the user clicks Yes, the program will close
        Me.Close() 'Exits the program
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnClearCurentSale_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClearCurentSale.Click
    'Clears the information from current sale and resets the form for the next sale
    txtShirts.Text = "" 'Clears the Shirts text box
    txtPremiumShirts.Text = ""  'Clears the Premium Shirts text box
    txtHats.Text = ""   'Clears the Hats text box
    txtStickers.Text = ""   'Clears the Stickers text box
    txtShirts.Focus()   'Puts the cursor in the Shirts text box

End Sub
```

Comment: Rather than catching exceptions, you could use `Integer.TryParse` and simply handle the return rather than exception.  You could avoid it altogether and make it simpler using `NumericupDowns`.  I cant find a SubTotal var so...

Comment: I need to know what to put after sngSubTotal = in the calculation section.
sngSubTotal = sngShirtPrice * intShirts + sngPremiumShirtPrice * intPremiumShirts + sngHatPrice * intHats + sngStickerPrice * intStickers?